# npm start : Failed start script 'ng serve'

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-start

> Just to clarify this: **I'm completely new to AngularJS** and to any
>   Web Technology. I'm a beginner when it comes to Web Development.
>
> *I tried to install it and I've gotta admit, after many "**Unknown Buttons Pressings**", I may have done a big mess, or maybe not.*

I followed **AngularJS Website's Tutorial** to install Angular and then I just wanted to push the "Red Button":

```
npm start
```

**But it threw an error saying:**

[image: Angular JS - npm start/ng serve Error]

---

### Actual Debug_Log here:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/apanpie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/apanpie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.0.5
3 info using node@v7.4.0
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /home/apanpie/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~prestart: apanpie@0.0.0
7 silly lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
8 info lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~start: apanpie@0.0.0
9 verbose lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
10 verbose lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~start: PATH: /home/apanpie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/apanpie/node_modules/.bin:/home/apanpie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/bin:/home/apanpie/bin:/home/apanpie/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
11 verbose lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~start: CWD: /home/apanpie
12 silly lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'ng serve' ]
13 silly lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
14 info lifecycle apanpie@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
15 verbose stack Error: apanpie@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
15 verbose stack Exit status 1
15 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/apanpie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
15 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
15 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
15 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/apanpie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
15 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
15 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
15 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
15 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
16 verbose pkgid apanpie@0.0.0
17 verbose cwd /home/apanpie/Desktop/angularTest
18 error Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
19 error argv "/home/apanpie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/bin/node" "/home/apanpie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/bin/npm" "start"
20 error node v7.4.0
21 error npm  v4.0.5
22 error code ELIFECYCLE
23 error apanpie@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the apanpie@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the apanpie package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     ng serve
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs apanpie
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls apanpie
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

So I've searched all around the Google Globe, but found nothing.

Also, I don't know if this is related, but in my TypeScript code:

```
import { View, Component } from '@angular2/core';
[... Components Here ... ]
```

it throws an error:

```
Cannot find module '@angular2/core'
```

If anyone could enlighten me, that would make me so happy!

Comment: can you show your app.component.html and .ts please

Comment: I can show you the main.ts :
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46a1d0297c2bab13bb0a1616b47e8d35

But 1. I don't know what you mean by "app.component.html" and 2. Don't know if this is related because this happens even if I have an empty folder (Which I don't know if it makes me sound stupid, as I said I'm a beginner my friend and Angular's Tutorial didn't clarify many things to me)

Comment: please  share complete code it wil be helpfull to identify the issue . one question . did you npm install run without any error ?

Comment: **npm install :** https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ce76295bec3639efd26795e33612cc19

**index.html :**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1c06a075f6fb36bcbfc72add88fa8f0

Comment: please check my answer I hope it will help you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are just starting angular 2 then please follow these steps as mention on the website of angular .

1     download the starter project from here . save it t to local folder lets say c:\test\  . location =     https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart this is all you need to do for hellp world app .

2)  go to command prompt then cd c:\test  .
3)  please insatll node js if not installed . 
4)  npm install 
5)  npm start

This will show b your first angular 2 hello world app .

this site is best to learn for angular 2 .
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

Comment: Hey thanks, I see now. I just didn't have some required files. But could you tell me which files are required before I make an "npm start" to run a local server? Also, do they need extra configurations? If you're comfortable with this of course !

Comment: it is mentioned in package.json file . So in short you need to tell what files /packages you need for your application and you can add them in package.json file . All packages oon which application depends and for development you need are mentioned here .

Answer (score 1):

The versions of **node/npm** and **angular/cli** may **not match**.
Look at this list [Check list](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) find your Angular version and check the node/npm version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

its a bit weird, but the root folder should be named like in this pattern, my-app, tour-of-heroes.

earlier today i had this problem, wrongly copied my-app like this:
sudo cp -rv my-app tourOfHeroes
then ran npm start inside tourOfHeroes
got that error

then after a few hours decided to do:
sudo cp -rv my-app tour-of-heroes
then ran npm start inside tour-of-heroes
then like magic it ran and im back in business