# How can i fix this npm start command?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, frontend, npm-install

When i want to test a front end repo and after installation of npm and npm start command it gives me this log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angulardemo2@0.0.0~prestart: angulardemo2@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle angulardemo2@0.0.0~start: angulardemo2@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle angulardemo2@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle angulardemo2@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\Courses\ChatBot\FourBots_FrontEnd\bot_front\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\CE\gcc\bin;E:\CE\gcc\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;E:\Software\MatLab\bin;E:\Software\New Folder\runtime\win64;E:\Software\New Folder\polyspace\bin;E:\Software\New Folder\bin;E:\Software\bin;C:\Program Files\Mono\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Python\Python37;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Python\Python37\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\MinGW\bin;C:MinGW\MYSYS\1.0\bin;e:\software\win32pe_edu;f:\win32pe_edu;f:\modelsim\win32pe_edu;E:\Software\Node;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;E:\Software\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\EaseUS\Todo Backup\bin\x64\
9 verbose lifecycle angulardemo2@0.0.0~start: CWD: E:\Courses\ChatBot\FourBots_FrontEnd\bot_front
10 silly lifecycle angulardemo2@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle angulardemo2@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle angulardemo2@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: angulardemo2@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid angulardemo2@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd E:\Courses\ChatBot\FourBots_FrontEnd\bot_front
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error angulardemo2@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angulardemo2@0.0.0 start script.
--
```

Comment: Please reformat this.

Comment: checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791944/npm-start-failed-start-script-ng-serve, it might be the same issue.

Comment: Might need some more context on your environment. Is this output from your script or an included library? `info it worked if it ends with ok`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm start -dd
```

**-dd**: to see logs